# Functional fixed points (ie fixed point of mapping from function space C[0,1] to itself)

Tags: integral-equations

I am looking for some tips or guidance as to what machinery in mathematica can help me get at this problem numerically. I am looking for fixed points of a mapping, but the objects in question are themselves functions. Hence I am looking for a fixed point function.

The setup (simplified version): 
suppose we restrict our search to continuous functions $f: [0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$. $p$ is a known parameter. I am looking for a fixed point (function) such that, for all $x\in [0,1]$, $f(x)$ solves

$$f(x) = \frac{x^p}{x^p + \int_0^1 f(x) x^p  \, dx }.$$

It's not as simple as finding lots of fixed points for each $x$ in isolation, as the value of the expression at a single $x$ depends on the entire function $f$. Any help to try and solve this type of thing numerically would be much appreciated.

Comment: I can think of multiple ways to go about this: -discretize your function by representing it by a vector and solve the discretized problem as an approximation. Then this might result in a finite dimensional `Eigenvalue` problem which can be solved with `Eigensystem` or `NDEigensystem`. -use `Interpolation` as function representation and sample and reinterpolate after each iteration. - use a variational approach to find the fixed point, perhaps the [`VariationalMethods`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/VariationalMethods/tutorial/VariationalMethods.html) package can help with that.

Comment: - perhaps the problem can be stated as an ordinary differential equation and either be directly solved by `DSolve`, numerically by `NDSolve` or iteratively by a [Picard iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem). I'm not sure if all of those methods can successfully tackle your problem, but all those alleys could be explored in Mathematica. Hope this gives you some ideas! When you try something and need further help, update your question with Mathematica code and specific questions, so that people can help you with the details.

Comment: The following should work: replace the integral with $c$. Solve for $f(x)$. Compute the integral as a function of $c$. Set the integral equal to $c$ and solve for $c$.

Comment: Thank you very much for these suggestions. 

I have tried the ODE approach. I don't think that it can be transformed into an ODE as I don't see a way to remove the integral. The ratio means it can't be transformed into a Fredholm equation, for which code already exists to numerically solve.

I will try discretizing in line with the great answer below. And I am a little lost by your suggestion, Lukas, although I will try work through it as well.

Comment: @LukasLang Great idea, this seems like the most simple and best approach!

Answer (score 7):

Just as an addition to @Okkes and @Ulrich's answer following the idea lined out by @LukasLang, we can also start with a symbolic solution of the integral for every `p`:

```
Integrate[x^p/(x^p + c) x^p, {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> p > 0 && c < -1]
```

> Hypergeometric2F1[1, 2 + 1/p, 3 + 1/p, -(1/c)]/(c + 2 c p)

Here we had to cheat a bit with the assumption `c < -1` to get the solution without condition, but we can see, that this is also a valid solution in the region `c > 0` which is of interest to us (here for `p==2`):

```
Plot[(Hypergeometric2F1[1, 2 + 1/p, 3 + 1/p, -(1/c)]/(c + 2 c p)) /. p -> 2, {c, -2, 2}]
```

[image: verifying that plot also works for c>0]

Next, we can use this solution to construct a function, which can numerically compute the constant `c` for arbitrary `p` (like @Okkes showed):

```
croot[p_?NumericQ] := Re[c /. FindRoot[
  Hypergeometric2F1[1, 2 + 1/p, 3 + 1/p, -(1/c)]/(c + 2 c p) == c,
  {c, 3/10}]
]
```

and then our solution will be

```
solution[p_] := x^p/(x^p + croot[p])
```

Now we can plot this for a range of `p` values:

```
Plot3D[solution[p], {x, 0, 1}, {p, 0.01, 4}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "p"}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}]
```

[image: Function plot for different values of p]

An interesting observation is, that `f[x]` seems to tend to a constant value as `p` tends to zero. With our symbolic solution from earlier we can determine that this value

```
Limit[Hypergeometric2F1[1, 2 + 1/p, 3 + 1/p, -(1/c)]/(c + 2 c p) - c, p -> 0, Direction -> -1] == 0
% && c > 0 // Solve
Limit[x^p/(x^p + c) /. First[%], p -> 0, Direction -> -1]
% // N
```

> -((-1 + c + c^2)/(1 + c)) == 0
>
> {{c -> 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[5])}}
>
> -(1/2) + Sqrt[5]/2
>
> 0.618034

is the golden ratio! :)

Answer (score 6):

**supplement**

The list of fixpoint-functions can be obtained strictly numerical (variable p) using Nintegrate:

```
int[c_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[x^(2 p)/(x^p + c), {x, 0, 1}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"   ]    

f\[Infinity] =Table[ x^ p /(x^p + c) /.NMinimize[{1, c == int[c, p]}, c][[2]] , {p, 1, 5}]
(*{x/(0.323829 + x), x^2/(0.227879 + x^2), x^3/(0.1782 + x^3)
, x^4/(0.147254 + x^4), x^5/(0.125923 + x^5)}*)

Plot[f\[Infinity], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very helpful addition. I was about to comment on Henrik's answer that it requires the integral to be analytically solvable by mathematica. Although the one I posted in the question is solvable, the actual ones I care about are generally not. So this is very useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is @Lucas suggestions in the comment.

```
    ClearAll[p, c]
    p = 2;
    f[x_] := x^p/(x^p + c)    

c = c /. Quiet@FindRoot[NIntegrate[f[x] x^p, {x, 0, 1}] == c, {c, 1}]
```

> 0.227879

```
fixedPoints = NSolve[f[x] == x, x]
```

> {{x -> 0.64873}, {x -> 0.35127}, {x -> 0.}}

```
 Plot[{f[x], x}, {x, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> {Flatten@Values@fixedPoints, 
   Flatten@Values@fixedPoints}]
```

[image]

@Thies's observation can be done analytically.

Set `p=0`. Then, $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+ c }$  where $c=\int_0^1 f(x)   \, dx$

$c=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+ c }   \, dx$

$c= \frac{1}{1+ c }x|_0^1  $

$c= \frac{1}{1+ c }  $

$c^2+c-1= 0  $

$c= \frac{-1\mp\sqrt{5}}{2}  $

Comment: `FixedPoint` appears to be faster than `NSolve` for this.

Answer (score 4):

This uses a discretization by piecewise-linear functions.

```
n = 1000;
x = Subdivide[0., 1., n - 1];
p = 2;
(* quadrature weights for trapezoidal rule *)
ω = ConstantArray[1./(n - 1), n];
ω[[1]] = ω[[n]] = 0.5/(n - 1);
```

Applying fixed point iteration; I use `Dot` and `ω` to compute the integral:

```
data = FixedPointList[
 f \[Function] x^p/(x^p + (x^p f).ω), 
 ConstantArray[0.5, n]
 ];
```

Checking the $L^\infty$ error:

```
Max[Abs[step[data[[-1]]] - data[[-1]]]]
```

> 2.22045*10^-16

Plotting the iterates:

```
ListLinePlot[
 data,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another method

```
k = 20; int[0] = NIntegrate[x^p, {x, 0, 1}]; 
f[i_, x_] := x^p/(x^p + int[i])
 Table[
 Do[int[i] = NIntegrate[f[i - 1, x]*x^p, {x, 0, 1}]; kp = i; 
  If[Abs[int[i] - int[i - 1]] > 10^-6, Continue[], Break[]], {i, 1, 
   k}]; x^p/(x^p + int[kp]), {p, 2, 7}]

(* {x^2/(0.227879 + x^2), x^3/(0.1782 + x^3), x^4/(
 0.147254 + x^4), x^5/(0.125923 + x^5), x^6/(0.110239 + x^6), x^7/(
 0.0981784 + x^7)}*)
```

For `p=7`

```
{ListPlot[Table[{i, int[i]}, {i, 0, kp}], PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[f[i, x], {i, 1, kp}]], {x, 0, 1}], 
 Plot[f[kp, x], {x, 0, 1}]}
```

[image: fig1]